# Writing to an XLST file without OLEDB

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I would like to know if there is any way I can easly create/write to an XLST file without having the Microsoft OLEDB driver installed.

Basically I've a file with all the inserts that need to be inserted like:

> insert into TABLE (x,y,z) values (1,2,3)

I've already loaded all the insert string and I would like to know if there is any easy way to create an Excel file with multiple sheets (one for each table) and all the data.

So far I've this:

```
    public void WriteToXLST(SQLStructure oStructure, string sFilenamePath)
    {

        string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;" +
                "Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 15.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0'", sFilenamePath);

        using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            cn.Open();

            foreach (string sInsertString in oStructure.InsertsList)
            {
                OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(sInsertString, cn);
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            cn.Close();

        }

    }
```

The problem is that I do want this to run without the need of instaling the OLEDB.Do you guys have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Use the [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/cc850837.aspx)

Comment: Hi,wont that SDK work well if I had all my inserts into XML? The problem is that my insert are SQL standard.

Comment: No, you can't expect a sql insert script to work if you don't want to install the engine that is needed to power it.